# Что лучше лучше использовать: if или исключения?

Tags: исключения, c++, css

Есть большая функция, которая выглядит примерно так:

```
void BigFunk(){
    // много разного кода, объединённого одной целью 
    // и содержащего конструкцию типа if (условие) return;
    // ...
    // ещё куча всякого кода
}
```

Чтобы уменьшить функцию, я решил выделить

```
// много разного кода, объединённого одной целью 
// и содежащего конструкцию типа if (условие) return;
```

в отдельную функцию. Как это лучше реализовать: при помощи if -

```
bool Part(){
    // много разного кода, объединённого одной целью 
    if (условие) return true;
    return false;
}
void BigFunk(){
    if (Part()) return;
    // ...
    // ещё куча всякого кода
}
```

или лучiе сделать это при помочи исключений:

```
void Part(){
    // много разного кода, объединённого одной целью 
    if (условие) throw 1;
}

void BigFunk(){
    try{
        Part();
    }
    catch(int t){
        return;
    }
    // ...
    // ещё куча всякого кода
}
```

Просто везде написано, что нужно стараться использовать исключения, но здесь речь идёт просто о выходе из функции при определённых условиях, и мне интересно, как лучше это сделать...

Comment: нет лучше if

Comment: сколько раз я видел подобный код:

    if (условие) return true;
    return false;

почему просто

    return условие;

не использовать?

Comment: видимо там не интересно)

Answer (score 7):

Смотрите на **исключения**, как на замаскированный нелокальный **goto** (longjmp()).

Т.е. если по смыслу надо прервать обработку и выйти в малое число точек алгоритма (начать там новый этап обработки (или аккуратно завершиться)), то исключение м.б. более удобным.

В случае же логического ветвления нормального хода обработки IMHO проверки флагов (кода возврата), т.е. **if** предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 4):

При обработке ошибок, если это позволяет язык программирования и используемая библиотека, конечно же лучше использовать исключения хотя бы потому, что ты сам определяешь, когда и какую ошибку тебе обработать. На хабре было несколько статей по этому поводу, например:

- [Коды возврата vs исключения — битва за контроль ошибок](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/programming/130611/)
- [Коды возврата & исключения](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/cpp/131212/)

UPD. Перечитал вопрос. Просто так городить огород с исключениями конечно же не стоит! Обработка исключений - процесс более серьезный, чем простое условие. Если это вопрос одного места в коде, почему нужно отказываться от обыкновенного ветвления?! :D

Comment: Если меня не подводит память, в книге Эндрю Ханта "Программист-прагматик" очень хорошо описывается когда стоит бросать исключения, без привязки к конкретному языку, всё чётко, понятно и по делу

Answer (score 2):

> Просто везде написано, что нужно стараться использовать исключения, но здесь речь идёт просто о выходе из функции при определённых условиях, и мне интересно, как лучше это сделать...

Где "везде написан" этот бред? Наоборот, исключений следует избегать. Использовать их надо только при обработке ошибок. Причём это должны быть не ошибки самого программиста, а ошибки окружения программы. Например, исключения можно возбуждать при загрузке отсутствующего или повреждённого файла, ошибке передачи по сети и т. д..

Также не должно быть исключений в конструкторах и деструкторах, потому что ресурсы могут быть некорректно освобождены, или произойдёт утечка памяти.

Comment: Не очень въезжаю, что такое "ошибка программиста" в таком случае. Ну к примеру тот же mysql++ возбуждает исключения по любому поводу, но в то же время они все относятся ко взаимодействию с базой. Это правильно с вашей точки зрения или нет?)

Comment: Я не знаком с mySQL++, поэтому не могу сказать, но *по любому поводу* исключения возбуждаться не должны.

 С моей точки зрения, если ошибка в самой библиотеке или переданы неверные параметры в функцию, то ошибку нужно обрабатывать не через исключения.

Comment: @GLmonster, полностью согласен. Исключения потому и названы исключениями, что предназначены для обработки ***исключительных*** ситуаций. А рядовые ситуации вполне можно обработать ифами.